How to make sure that the data modification events are delivered to SQS or Kinesis in correct order?
Let's assume the following situation:
There is a backend service, and it has CRUD endpoints for "insert", "update" and "delete" requests.
Each endpoint updates relational database and right after that, it sends out a data modification message to SQS (or Kinesis).
SQS has been configured as FIFO, i.e. the records will be consumed in the same order as they were delivered, and there will be no duplicates. And Kinesis is FIFO anyway.
Now assume three requests arrive in sequence.

request 1: creates a record with id=5, then sends insertion event to SQS
request 2: updates a record with id=5, then sends update event to SQS
request 3: deletes a record with id=5, then sends deletion event to SQS

Let's also assume that request 1 was preempted by another task right after the record was inserted, for example by garbage collector.
As a result, insertion event arrives last at SQS, even though it chronologically was executed first (the delivery order is hence update, followed by delete, followed by insert).
My question is, how to guarantee that the delivery order is the same with the actual order of data modification queries (in my example, insert, followed by update, followed by delete)?

Take a look at Transactional Outbox pattern from AWS Prescriptive Guidance https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/cloud-design-patterns/transactional-outbox.html
To guarantee that the delivery order of messages to Amazon SQS (or Kinesis) matches the actual order of database modifications, you can implement the Outbox Pattern. We considered this for one of our projects and thought this was an overkill, but this seems to solve the order issue

that's very helpful, thanks for sharing. this page mentions two ways of dealing with the problem. out of curiosity, which approach did you take? outbox table or CDC? (basically the point is to ingest the data into queue once it's been persisted into storage rather than do it prematurely at the application level)
